# Square matrix of A has nonzero determinant if and only if the characteristic equation has all nonzero roots

Tags: roots, matrix-equations

Please help me with this. How do I prove that a square matrix A has non-zero determinant(nonsingular) if and only if the characteristic equation of A has all non-zero roots.
Its probably very simple...

Thank you in advance

Comment: The determinant is the product of the roots of the characteristic equation.

Comment: Wlecome to Math.SE ! Can you show us what you have already tried ?

Comment: It might be easier to show that $\det A = 0$ **iff** $t \mapsto \det (tI-A)$ has a zero at zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $p(\lambda)=\det (A-\lambda I)$.  So, $p(0)=\det A$ and the result follows.